# Any differences between Apollo PEX-B and Sharkbite PEX-B - Need to Run through Wooden Studs

Tags: plumbing, pex

I noticed that near me, HD carries Apollo PEX-B and Lowe's sells Sharkbite PEX-B. Are there any differences between these two in terms of flexibility, durability, etc? I wasn't sure if one brand was considered better than the other, and I can't find much comparing the two. I would appreciate any insight!

As an aside, I noticed that Sharkbite mentions using abrasion clips when passing through a wood stud. I was under the impression that they are only needed for metal studs, unless the PEX is penetrating the wood at an angle or rubbing against the stud, joist, etc. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: It is good practice and cheap insurance to use the abrasion clips, Pex will expand and contract with temperature fluctuations.

Comment: The main reason they carry different brands is so that they don't have to price-match. This is also why you'll often find funny things with model numbers of apparently identical tools when they both carry the same brand - QZXY-HD is not the same as QZXY-L even if they are otherwise identical and come off the same assembly line.